# Source that "Yehi Khevod" should be said with special intensity

Tags: sources-mekorot, kavana-concentration, artscroll, pesukei-dezimra

Some editions of the ArtScroll siddur have the following instruction before *Yehi Khevod* (in *pesukei dezimra*):

> The following prayer should be recited with special intensity.

What is the source for this?

Comment: In the _sidurim_ based on Rav Chayim Vital and the Ar"i, there are lengthy explanations about how each _pasuk_ contains the 4-letter Name, for a total of 18, which (besides matching the 6 permutations of the 3-letter name ש-די) correspond to parallel 9s, representing the world above and the world below, and represented by the parallel טs in the name מטטרון, who serves as the intermediary between the two worlds. This connection, expressed through God's name(s), engenders the special intensity.

Comment: There is a certain collection of _sidurim_ that contain a lot of counting based commentary, especially in terms of counting instances of the 4-letter Name. See also the compilation after _birchos k'ri'as Sh'ma_ at _ma'ariv_ outside the land, and _T'hilim_ 27 (according to Rabbi Shneur Leiman).

Comment: @WAF "...and represented by the parallel טs in the name מטטרון..." See *Chulin* ([60a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=60&format=text)) that the first verse (*y'hi ch'vod*) was recited by Metatron (according to *Tosafos* s.v. פסוק זה; see also *Tosafos* on *Y'vamos* 16b s.v. פסוק זה) when species of grass differentiated themselves in Creation based on their inference from HaShem's command to the trees.

Comment: R' Shimon Schwab in the book of his shiurim on prayer, says that this is "of an especially elevated nature, and therefore one should try not to omit it," but doesn't actually speak about *how* one should say it.

Comment: I often wondered whether it was a misprint and the comment was meant to appear before Ashrei.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Sidur Bes Yaakov* (Emden) says of this paragraph:

> אומרו במתון וכונה ושמחה

That is:

> Say it with calmness, direction of thought, and joy.

Comment: I can't find this in the [old edition](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22431&st=&pgnum=196) (it should go after the top three lines). In the [newer one](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=42760&st=&pgnum=103) it's in square brackets. Is it a later addition?